# Sign of a symbolic expression as a function of parameter values

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, parametric-functions

I need to know the sign of the following expression for `p[t] = z/(1-a)`, as a function of the parameters `{a, b, c, z}`:

```
-b - (b c z (1 + c p[t]))/(1 - b c + c p[t])^2 + (b c z)/(
1 - b c + c p[t]) + (-b^2 c + a b (1 - 2 c p[t]))/(
1 - b c + c p[t]) - (
c (-b^2 c p[t] + a b (p[t] - c p[t]^2)))/(1 - b c + c p[t])^2
```

I am generally interested in the region where the parameters can take the following values:

$$0<a\leq1 \quad \quad b>0\quad \quad 0<c\leq1 \quad \quad z>0\\$$

In particular, I would at least like to find the sign for these special cases, if possible:

- for $a=c=1$
- for $c=1$

Comment: Look up `Reduce[]`

Comment: If I remember correctly this is your second question and although we referred you to the centre to read more about asking a question/formatting, keep it tight, explaining what really is going on, etc/ you still didn't do it. Please, do it now

Comment: Sektor, I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at using Reduce on your problem.

First we will define your function p[t], then assign parts of your problem to a couple of variables to make this easier to see and finally try using Reduce to see when the sign of your expression will be negative. Note: Your p[t] doesn't depend on t. Is this perhaps a typo or did you mean something different?

```
p[t_] := z/(1 - a);
assumptions = 0<a<=1 && 0<b && 0<c<=1 && 0<z;
expression = -b - (b c z (1 + c p[t]))/(1 - b c + c p[t])^2 +
  (b c z)/(1 - b c + c p[t]) + (-b^2 c + a b (1 - 2 c p[t]))/
  (1 - b c + c p[t]) - (c (-b^2 c p[t] + a b (p[t] - c p[t]^2)))/
  (1 - b c + c p[t])^2;

FullSimplify[Reduce[assumptions && expression < 0], assumptions]
```

and the result is a>=1 || (-1+a)^4 (-1+b c)+(-1+a)^2 c (-2+b c+a (-2+3 b c)) z+(-1+a^2) c^2 z^2 < 0.

So the first alternative in that says the sign of your original expression should be negative when a >= 1, but we already told it that 0< a <=1 that seems leave only a==1. Yet when we try substituting 1 for a in your original expression you find lots of zero denominators because p[t]==z/0. If you look at Limit[expression, a->1] then that says the result is -2b and one of your conditions is that b is positive so that would give a negative sign, but only in the limit and not when a==1. It seems odd and troubling that Reduce would return a>=1 when it is given 0< a <=1.

The second alternative says your original expression will be negative exactly when this new and almost as complicated expression will be negative. Testing that to see if it really is true seems more difficult. You might try a little Monte Carlo random trial and error, but thus far I haven't found a way to verify it is true for all cases.

You can then try to replace < with == or with > in that Reduce and look at where your sign will be zero or will be positive.

Now let's try one of your special cases.

```
assumptions = a==1 && 0<b && c==1 && 0<z;
FullSimplify[Reduce[assumptions && expression < 0], assumptions]
```

and the result is False, as it is for == and >. That indicates that Reduce was simply not able to find any combination that satisfied the conditions. That is probably mostly due to your p[t]==z/0 when a==1.

Now let's make one last try for your final special case.

```
assumptions = 0<a<=1 && 0<b && c==1 && 0<z;
FullSimplify[Reduce[assumptions && expression == 0], assumptions]
```

and the result is z == -(((-1+a)(-2+b+a (-2+3 b)+Sqrt[8 a (1+a)-16 a (1+a) b+(b+3 a b)^2]))/(2 (1+a))). So the sign of your original expression will be zero (neither positive nor negative) exactly when z equals that expression.

The results from all this do not appear to be particularly satisfying. Perhaps you can see if there is enough from this to serve your purpose.

Comment: Bill, thanks a lot. Very careful scrutinizing you did. I will analyse everything again and see what happens